# Use of 'You can certainly try'

Tags: sentence-usage

Does 'You can certainly try' mean, I already know that what ever you are going to do, is not going to work, but you are free to try it(a negative tone) ,or it just means go ahead and try(a positive tone).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It means that whatever is being attempted has no guarantee of working, but it may be possible.  It's not impossible but may be highly improbable.

Comment: I agree. It expresses doubt and possibly sarcasm.

Comment: Yes, it has certainly been appropriated to imply sarcasm.  Similar to another expression Good luck! with an exclamation mark.  These days, this is exclusively a sarcastic comment expressing doubt about a successful outcome